# Javascript Form Selection

Tags: javascript, html

I want to give users the options of two different HTML forms, based on a users selection. Gathered from here and a couple of other resources, here is what I have so far. It works in my Edge browser but not in Chrome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <script language="JavaScript">
function showInput() {
    document.getElementById('display1').innerHTML = 
                document.getElementById('FRAC_MULTI').value;
}

function changeOptions(selectEl) {
  let selectedValue = selectEl.options[selectEl.selectedIndex].value;
  let subForms = document.getElementsByClassName('className')
  for (let i = 0; i < subForms.length; i += 1) {
    if (selectedValue === subForms[i].name) {
      subForms[i].setAttribute('style', 'display:block')
    } else {
      subForms[i].setAttribute('style', 'display:none') 
    }
  }
}

  </script>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>

<h2>Av. Temp Recorder</h2>
Choose Temperature Gauge:
<select onchange="changeOptions(this)">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Select Option</option value="">
  <option value="form_1">Temp LVL 1</option>
  <option value="form_2">Temp LVL 2</option>
</select>

<form class="className" name="form_1" id="form_1" style="display:none">
LVL 1 Configuration Form
  <!---- THIS IS FORM 1---->
</form>

<form class="className" name="form_2" id="form_2" style="display:none">
LVL 2 Configuration Form<br>
  <!---- THIS IS FORM 2---->
Fractal Multiplier:<input name="name" size="50" value="500000" id="FRAC_MULTI">
</form>
<br><br><br>
  <input type="submit" onclick="showInput();"><br/>
  <label>User input: </label><br><br><pre>
{
    "FRAC_MULTI":"<span id="display1"></span>",
}
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

When I select the first option I see the correct text but when selecting second option in Chrome, I do not see any form.  In Edge I see the form when selecting option 2 AND the thext when selecting option 1.

In Chrome, it works if I only use text in each form (as shown in form_1 above) so it seems to be an issue with the form being hidden by the code.

Any suggestions as to what the issue may be?

Comment: Please be more specific about what the code should do and what it isn't doing as expected as well as any errors encountered. See [ask]

Comment: do you have any console logs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The situation is the following: when you find all the items with `getElementsByClassName` then you get back a list of HTMLCollection with child items. When you refering to `subForms[1].name`, you get back the input field in case of chrome instead of the form's name attribute. If you rename the input field's name attribute to name2, your script will work or you can use the `subForms[i].getAttribute('name')` and then you will get back the attribute instead of something.
In edge, somewhy when you run manually the code, the input element will be returned, but it seems when it runs the code it does some magic trick and it priorities the attribute value instead of the element. Maybe because it detects you want to compare a string instead of an `Element`.

Please note: HTMLCollection items can be accessed by their name, id, or index number.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, it appears as if you are 100% correct and your answer provides an excellent explanation!  I did not care for how I had used "name" for the attribute name, so I have changed that.

Comment: I would also use `getAttribute()` with proper naming, because in longer term, it will pay out, if you do it properly. ;)